# how to trim a date to format of 00/00/0000?

Tags: text-processing, date

I want to pad and substitute the already extracted date in a .csv file from 0/0/0000 to 00/00/0000 for instance 1/9/2016 --> 01/09/2016

I have this script

```
sed 's/\/1\//\/01\//g; s/\/2\//\/02\//g; s/\/3\//\/03\//g; s/\/4\//\/04\//g; s/\/5\//\/05\//g; s/\/6\//\/06\//g; s/\/7\//\/07\//g; s/\/8\//\/08\//g; s/\/9\//\/09\//g' file_name.csv > file_name2.csv
sed 's/,1\//,01\//g; s/,2\//,02\//g; s/,3\//,03\//g; s/,4\//,04\//g; s/,5\//,05\//g; s/,6\//,06\//g; s/,7\//,07\//g; s/,8\//,08\//g; s/,9\//,09\//g' file_name2.csv > file_name3.csv
```

Comment: ***[trim](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=define+trim):*** make (something) neat or of the required size or form by cutting away irregular or unwanted parts.  (example) “trim the grass using a sharp mower”; *synonyms:* cut, etc.  Using the word ***trim*** when you’re talking about ***adding*** characters is confusing.

Comment: @G-Man, so edit it to say 'pad' instead of 'trim' instead of moaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sed statement will add a `0` to the first two numbers if they are single digits:

```
sed -e 's!^[0-9]/!0&!' -e 's!/\([0-9]/\)!/0\1!'
```

e.g.

```
$ cat x
1/1/1970
10/1/2000
10/10/2100

$ sed -e 's!^[0-9]/!0&!' -e 's!/\([0-9]/\)!/0\1!' x
01/01/1970
10/01/2000
10/10/2100
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is simple only if you make a lot of assumptions.  Since the question did not provide an example, here are some realistic assumptions:

- the delimiter between fields of the date is <kbd>/</kbd>
- csv files have more than one column
- the date can be in any column
- other columns might have numbers

The example by Stephen did not address the last three of these.  Here is a script showing two improvements:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=foo.csv
echo GIVEN
cat $INPUT
echo BEFORE
sed -e 's!^[0-9]/!0&!' -e 's!/\([0-9]/\)!/0\1!' <$INPUT
echo IMPROVED
sed     \
        -e 's,^\([0-9][/]\),0\1,' \
        -e 's,\([,/]\)\([0-9]\),\10000\2,g' \
        -e 's,^0*\([0-9]\{2\}[/]\),\1,' \
        -e 's,\([,/]\)0*\([0-9]\{2\}\),\1\2,g' \
        <$INPUT
echo BETTER
sed     \
        -e 's,^\([0-9][/]\),0\1,' \
        -e 's,\([,/]\)\([0-9]\),\10000\2,g' \
        -e 's,^0*\([0-9]\{2\}[/]\),\1,' \
        -e 's!0*\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([,/]\)0*\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([/]\)0*\([0-9]\{4,\}\)!\1\2\3\4\5!g' \
        <$INPUT
```

and output from running the script:

```
GIVEN
1/1/1970
10/1/2000
10/10/2100
first,1/1/1970
second,10/1/2000
third,10/10/2100
9term,1/1/1
BEFORE
01/01/1970
10/01/2000
10/10/2100
first,1/01/1970
second,10/01/2000
third,10/10/2100
9term,1/01/1
IMPROVED
01/01/1970
10/01/2000
10/10/2100
first,01/01/1970
second,10/01/2000
third,10/10/2100
9term,01/01/01
BETTER
01/01/1970
10/01/2000
10/10/2100
first,01/01/1970
second,10/01/2000
third,10/10/2100
9term,01/01/0001
```

A complete solution would take into account the boundaries better (such as whether to discount things like `1/1/1text`), and quotes (csv files use double-quotes for working around commas within columns).